# Magento upgrade 1.4.1 to 1.6.2 incomplete product data

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

After moving my magento to a test area and upgraded my version to 1.6.2 my product data got corrupted. prices/statusses aren't in the overview and products aren't shown at the front-end.
i've tried to import an export from the live site but it tell's me that statusses contain unknown values. If i try to import by profile it tells me that the images can't be found.. which is correct because they havent been copied.. this shouldn't be a problem? 
What still surprises is me.. is eventhough the data is in the database it doesn't show anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Since Upgrading from 1.4.2 to latest version in not simple task as data structure has been changed after 1.4, It will be better if you can enable the system logs from backend it will show the error.. Or you can try Indexer from command prompt also...

If you are able to see products at backend then see if their visibility is true for frontend

See this url for more info
http://www.sebday.com/2011/10/magento-1-4-upgrade-to-1-6-database-errors/

Note: Also check the table in database

catalog_product_index_website
It should have the structure

`website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Website ID',
`website_date` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Website Date',
`rate` float DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Rate',

Let me know if are getting some error